# FooterView not showing up in Storyboard UICollectionView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, uicollectionview

I am trying to put a footer view into my UICollectionView in Storyboard but when I click the footer view radio button, the image for the collection view updates but no views are added to the hierarchy as you can see in the image below. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After you check "Section Footer" checkbox (not radio button) Collection Reusable View item should appear inside Collection View hierarchy which is in the left panel. Now I am not seeing it at all in your panel. Something is wrong with your collection or your Xcode. For example in my XCode 7.2, when I check both header and footer checkboxes, collection view hierarchy looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Try to update your Xcode or create new storyboard file.

Comment: I noticed you use .xib file. So I also tried to play with XIB and I faced the same issue. So if you use storyboard file, you won't experience any issues. Otherwise you will have to draw your footer programmatically.